# rsync is nesting the source directory in the destination as if it had no trailing slash when --files-from option is used

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, nfs

Pulling my hair out here trying to get this to work. Heres an example of the details and command.

I have a file with a list of directories named list.txt The contents look like this:

`HYTTCCCXX
HYTVNCCXX
HYV5TCCXX`

My rsync command looks like:
`rsync -av --recursive --files-from='/tmp/list.txt' /test/apple/ /destination/files/`

The issue is that when I run the command, it includes both 
`/test/` (which is an autofs top level, so contains nothing really) and `/test/apple/` in the files to be transferred. Causing the files to be written twice into the destination as if I left the trailing slash off my source.

So the destination ends up with both the directories in the list, and another copy of the source like: 
`/destination/files/HYW22CCXX
 /destination/files/HYTVNCCXX
 /destination/files/HYV5TCCXX
 /destination/files/test/apple/HYW22CCXX
 /destination/files/test/apple/HYW22CCXX
 /destination/files/test/apple/HYTVNCCXX`

So I end up with 2 copies of everything.

Ive tried every combination of exclude like `--exclude='/test/apple/'` or `--exclude='/test/*` or `--exclude='apple/*` to try and keep it from being included. But nothing works.

Any ideas? Im going bananas trying to figure this out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the `--files-from` option implies `--relative`.

Quote from the rsync man page, the section on `--files-from`:

> The --relative (-R) option is implied, which preserves the path information that is specified for each item in the file (use --no-relative or --no-R if you want to turn that off).

Try the following options and see if it helps:
`rsync -av --recursive --no-relative --files-from='/tmp/list.txt' /test/apple/ /destination/files/`